# Display cinema seat layout of their own session (PHP & Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `seat` (
  `Seat_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Hall_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Seat_No` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Seat_Price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Seat_Status` text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `hall` (
  `Hall_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Cinema_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Hall_Size` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Num_Seats` int(11) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `reservation_seat` (
  `ResevationSeat_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Seat_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Reservation_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `ticket_reservation` (
  `Reservation_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Member_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Reservation_Date` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Hall_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Showing_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Start_Time` time NOT NULL,
  `End_Time` time NOT NULL,
  `Session_Status` varchar(15) NOT NULL
)
```

The code here is how I display the seat from A row to C row

```
<tr class="a-row">
            <?php 
                $mysql = 
                "SELECT * FROM seat, session, hall 
                WHERE Seat_No LIKE 'A_%' 
                AND seat.Hall_No = hall.Hall_No 
                AND session.Session_ID = $sesid 
                AND session.Hall_No = hall.Hall_No ";

                $result = mysqli_query($connect,$mysql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {       
            ?>
                    <td></t><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="<?php echo $row['Seat_ID']?>" id="<?php echo $row['Seat_No']?>"><label id="available" for="<?php echo $row['Seat_No']?>"><?php echo $row["Seat_No"]?></label></td>

            <?php   
                }
            ?>  
            </tr>
```

What I want to do is check the database from reservation_seat and ticket_reservation, if there is a reserved seat, then i will use javascript to change the id from 'available' to 'booked'.

```
$checkreserve = 
"SELECT * from 
ticket_reservation as tr, 
reservation_seat as rs 
WHERE tr.Session_ID = $sesid 
AND tr.Reservation_ID = rs.Reservation_ID";
```

These are the lines i coded to check if it displays the correct booked seat from their own session.

Comment: Stop. NEVER use implicit (comma) joins. Fix that. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), and then get back to us.

Comment: This looks like MySQL, not SQL Server. Why have you tagged both?